# J-Monkey subclass

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jmonkeyengine

I'm new in java and J-monkey and I'm trying to make a java game so for the Menu I have made a enum so I can Switch between any of my State but I want to keep the main file shorter so it can be easily to read so I'm making subclass the problem is that when run the game it give me an error that say "Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[LWJGL Renderer Thread,5,main] NullPointerException" I think this problem has to be something whit the pipeline Here is the code of my main file:

```
package mygame;

import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
import com.jme3.font.BitmapText;
import com.jme3.material.Material;
import com.jme3.math.ColorRGBA;
import com.jme3.math.Vector3f;
import com.jme3.renderer.RenderManager;
import com.jme3.scene.Spatial;
import com.jme3.scene.Geometry;

import com.jme3.input.*;
import com.jme3.input.controls.*;

public class Main extends SimpleApplication {

//GameStates
enum GameState{Logo, Menu, Playing, Option};
GameState gameState = GameState.Logo;

//Class Variables
Logo logo;


public Main() {

logo = new Logo();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main app = new Main();
    app.start();
}

public static void logo(String[] args) {
    Logo app = new Logo();
    app.start();
}

@Override
public void simpleInitApp() {
    //Load
    flyCam.setMoveSpeed(20);
    if(gameState == GameState.Logo){
        logo.simpleInitApp();
    }
}

@Override
public void simpleUpdate(float tpf) {

}

@Override
public void simpleRender(RenderManager rm) {
    //TODO: add render code
    //Load
    if(gameState == GameState.Logo)
    {

    }

}
}
```

And here is my Logo subclass:

```
package mygame;

    import com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication;
    import com.jme3.renderer.RenderManager;
    import com.jme3.scene.Spatial;

    public class Logo extends SimpleApplication {

    @Override
    public void simpleInitApp() {
    Spatial Logo_Model = assetManager.loadModel("Models/Teapot/Logo.obj");
    rootNode.attachChild(Logo_Model);
    }

    public void simpleRender(RenderManager rm) {
    //Load

    }
    }
```

**I have move down the stack trace that I think is giving my problem so you don't have to read all the Exception just scroll down**

Full Exception stack trace:
Nov 09, 2013 11:29:32 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root          0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:49 AM com.jme3.system.JmeDesktopSystem initialize
   INFO: Running on jMonkeyEngine 3.0.0 Beta
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:49 AM com.jme3.system.Natives extractNativeLibs
   INFO: Extraction Directory: C:\Users\Zero\Documents\Basic_Test_menu
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:49 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay run
   INFO: Using LWJGL 2.8.4
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:49 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglDisplay createContext
   INFO: Selected display mode: 800 x 600 x 0 @0Hz
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
   INFO: Adapter: igdumd64
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
   INFO: Driver Version: null
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
   INFO: Vendor: Intel
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
   INFO: OpenGL Version: 3.1.0 - Build 9.17.10.2932
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
   INFO: Renderer: Intel(R) HD Graphics
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglContext printContextInitInfo
   INFO: GLSL Ver: 1.40 - Intel Build 9.17.10.2932
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglTimer 
   INFO: Timer resolution: 1,000 ticks per second
   Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.renderer.lwjgl.LwjglRenderer initialize
   INFO: Caps: [FrameBuffer, FrameBufferMRT, FrameBufferMultisample, OpenGL20, OpenGL21,     OpenGL30, OpenGL31, ARBprogram, GLSL100, GLSL110, GLSL120, GLSL130, GLSL140,   VertexTextureFetch, TextureArray, FloatTexture, FloatColorBuffer, FloatDepthBuffer,   PackedFloatTexture, SharedExponentTexture, PackedFloatColorBuffer, NonPowerOfTwoTextures,  MeshInstancing, VertexBufferArray, Multisample, PackedDepthStencilBuffer]
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.asset.AssetConfig loadText
    WARNING: Cannot find loader com.jme3.scene.plugins.blender.BlenderModelLoader
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.asset.DesktopAssetManager 
    INFO: DesktopAssetManager created.
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.renderer.Camera 
    INFO: Camera created (W: 800, H: 600)
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.renderer.Camera 
    INFO: Camera created (W: 800, H: 600)
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.input.lwjgl.LwjglMouseInput initialize
    INFO: Mouse created.
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:50 AM com.jme3.input.lwjgl.LwjglKeyInput initialize
    INFO: Keyboard created.
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
    INFO: AudioRenderer supports 64 channels
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
    INFO: Audio effect extension version: 1.0
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.audio.lwjgl.LwjglAudioRenderer initInThread
    INFO: Audio max auxilary sends: 4
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.material.MaterialDef 
    INFO: Loaded material definition: Unshaded
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.scene.Node attachChild
    INFO: Child (BitmapFont) attached to this node (null)
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51

```
AM com.jme3.app.Application handleError SEVERE: Uncaught exception
   thrown in Thread[LWJGL Renderer Thread,5,main]

   java.lang.NullPointerException
at mygame.Logo.simpleInitApp(Logo.java:17)
at mygame.Main.simpleInitApp(Main.java:46)
at com.jme3.app.SimpleApplication.initialize(SimpleApplication.java:225)
at                com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.initInThread(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:130)
at com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay.run(LwjglAbstractDisplay.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)


    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.renderer.lwjgl.LwjglRenderer cleanup
    INFO: Deleting objects and invalidating state
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.input.lwjgl.LwjglMouseInput destroy
    INFO: Mouse destroyed.
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.input.lwjgl.LwjglKeyInput destroy
    INFO: Keyboard destroyed.
    Nov 09, 2013 11:29:51 AM com.jme3.system.lwjgl.LwjglAbstractDisplay deinitInThread
    INFO: Display destroyed.
```

Comment: Please post your exception stack trace.

Comment: Do you mean the error? I don't have any just some Import unused and some variable too ?

Comment: No, I don't mean the compilation error. I mean the exception stack trace. You should Google "What is an exception stack trace?"

Comment: ok I edit the post and put the trace hehe I learn something new thanks

Comment: and which line is line 17 of Logo.java?

Comment: this one :     Spatial Logo_Model = assetManager.loadModel("Models/Teapot/Logo.obj");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `assetManager` is null at that point in time. Either you assign it too late or you forget to assign it at all.

Comment: so you are saying for the assentmanager that I may not declare a varible in the logo.java or that I may put the Code in in the wrong method?

Comment: No! I'm saying that assetmanager is null. Make it not be null! Give it a value! Do you understand what null means?

Comment: By the way, in C++, declaring a variable creates an object. In Java, this is not true. If you are coming from C++, this might be the source of your confusion.

Comment: haha you are right I have use c++ and c# so im new in java xD you tell me the true it wass null because the logo.java never start that why it get null so I put logo.start(); and it work but it reset my cams setting from the flyCam and the debug open again so it will be hard xD